# Card Vue misalignment + portion star rating

Tags: html, vue.js, vue-component

I am having some confusion in card Vue.
I am creating a page and after building it, I have several problems.
[My website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnNlD.jpg)

As it is visible here my button and my star rating and not correctly aligned and they have overlap. So I was wondering how can I solve this.
Also, I was wondering how I can convert my 10-star rating to a 5-star rating with portion. (instead of 7/10 I want to have 3.5/5)
Also I am curious If i can show this 3.5/5 beside the stars after going over the rate.

I have uploaded my corresponding code about it.

```
<el-row :gutter="20 ">
            <el-col :span="4 " v-for="o in recommended " :key="o.isbn " :offset="0 ">
                <el-card :body-style="{ padding: '0px' } " style="margin-top:15px;height:400px;overflow:auto;position:relative ">
                    <el-image style="width: 100%;height:240px; " :src="o.img_l " fit="cover "></el-image>
                    <h4 style="padding:0 10px;margin:0 ">{{o.book_title}}</h4>
                    <el-rate v-model="o.score " style="padding:10px 10px;" :max=10></el-rate>
                    <el-button type="danger " @click="liked_btn(o) " style="min-width:128px ">
                        Submit feedback
                    </el-button>
                </el-card>
            </el-col>
        </el-row>
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: to make 10 stars 5, divide the rating by 2, then obviously change `:max=10` to `:max=5`

Comment: No I mean I want to show 5 stars only but allow people to vote a portion of a star. (for example they can vote 3.5 star).

Comment: use `allow-half` prop, is found in the docs https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/rate

Comment: Oh thanks I found it! it seems it was false by default, How about the alignment? The stars and button and text are not well formatted and having overlaps!

Comment: having 10 is just too many to fit, make it 5, then adjust your cols so columns don't squish then it should fit fine https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/layout#responsive-layout

Comment: Thanks, I could manage the first part, If i want to somehow unify the internal format of the cards, this does not happen because of the different lengths of the books' names. Also, the submission button is not in a fixed position relative to the size of each card. what should I do?